# What is the difference between stringstream object() and object?

Tags: c++

In my program I have

```
stringstream strumien(); //1
stringstream strumien;  // 2
strumien<<"napis "<<8<<endl;
```

and the first line generates the following error

> invalid operands of types 'std::stringstream() {aka
>   std::basic_stringstream()}' and 'const char [7]' to binary
>   'operator<<'

But the second one works properly. (of course always one of them is commented out)
So what is the difference between them? Because I always thought that they are equal definitions of an object.

Comment: The first one is probably MVP. It thinks youre declaring a function that takes no arguments and returns a stringstream.

Comment: And with that @Borgleader is referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse FYI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something which looks like a function declaration *is* a function declaration. That is

```
T name();
```

declares a function called `name` taking no arguments and returning a `T`. This is called the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). There are two potential fixes to avoiding this problem: leaving the parenthesis off or using C++2011 "uniform initialization" (which is a gross misnomer):

```
T name{};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line is in fact a declaration. Even if it seems to be the same as your second, it is not...

So

```
T name();
```

**declares** a function `name` return an object of type `T`.

The C++ standard states this ambiguity :

> **6.8 Ambiguity resolution [stmt.ambig]**
>
> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression-statement with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.

This ambiguity is also called [The Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

---

There is a new way to solve this since the C++11, it is called the [**uniform initialization syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax).

It works like :

```
T name{};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line is ambiguous in the formal grammar: Either it could be interpreted as a function declaration or a declaration and instantiation of an object with a no-arg constructor. The language opts to treat it as a function declaration since it is possible to forego the parentheses to invoke the no-arg constructor.