# What's the difference between `Object obj(args...)` and `Object obj{args...}`?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, uniform-initialization

The draft book [Effective C++11](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/01/effective-c11-content-and-status.html) by Scott Meyers states:

> Distinguish () and {} when creating objects

What's the difference between `Object obj(args...)` and `Object obj{args...}`? and why Scott says so.

**Update:**

The question [How to use C++11 uniform initialization syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax) asks for HOW, and this question asks for WHY.

**Update2:**

I find the following link is helpful and completely answers this question:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use C++11 uniform initialization syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, that question asks for HOW, this question asks for WHY.

Comment: This question doesn't ask "WHY", and the other question covers what uniform initialization does.

Comment: One is direct initialization and the other is list initialization. The standard has tons of specific information on both of them.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I cite Scott's statement and want to know why he says so.

Comment: Oh, why distinguish? Because braces especially can result in something unexpected, mostly due to list constructors.

Comment: You'd have to ask Scott Meyers why his book says what it says. There's a chance that his book explains it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the difference between `Object obj(args...)` and `Object obj{args...}`?

The first is *direct-initialization* while the second is *direct-list-initialization*. This is mentioned in two different sections:

*§8.5/16 [dcl.init]*

> The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> ```
>  T x(a);
>  T x{a};
> ```
>
> as well as in `new` expressions (5.3.4), `static_cast` expressions (5.2.9), functional notation type conversions (5.2.3), and base and member initializers (12.6.2) is called ***direct-initialization***.

and *§8.5.4/1 [dcl.init.list]*

> *List-initialization* is initialization of an object or reference from a *braced-init-list*. Such an initializer is called an *initializer list*, and the comma-separated *initializer-clauses* of the list are called the *elements* of the initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. **List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy-initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called *direct-list-initialization*** and list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called *copy-list-initialization*.

---

There are a few differences between the two:

- If the type being constructed has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` argument, *direct-list-initialization* will always favor that constructor. Other constructors will only be considered if the `initializer_list` constructor is not viable. *§13.3.1.7/1 [over.match.list]*
- *direct-list-initialization* does not allow narrowing conversions within the argument list. *§8.5.4/3 [dcl.init.list]*
- If the type being initialized is an aggregate, *direct-list-initialization* will perform aggregate initialization. *§8.5.4/3 [dcl.init.list]*
- The order of evaluation of the elements of a *braced-init-list* is from left to right. *§8.5.4/4 [dcl.init.list]*
- You can avoid the most vexing parse by using *direct-list-initialization*

```
  struct foo{};
  struct bar 
  {    
    bar(foo const&) {}
  };

  bar b1(foo()); // most vexing parse
  bar b2(foo{}); // all 3 of the following construct objects of type bar
  bar b3{foo()};
  bar b4{foo{}};
```

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `Object obj(args...)` and `Object{args...}` depends on the constructors defined in `Object`.

Take the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A
{
   A(int a, int b) {std::cout << "Came to A::A()\n";}
};

struct B
{
   B(int a, int b) {std::cout << "Came to B::B(int, int)\n";}
   B(std::initializer_list<int> in) {std::cout << "Came to B::B(std::initializer_list<int>)\n";}
};

int main()
{
   A a1(10, 20); // Resolves to A(int, int)
   A a2{10, 20}; // Resolves to A(int, int)
   A a3{30};     // Does not resolve to anything. It's a compiler error.

   B b1(10, 20); // Resolves to B(int, int)
   B b2{10, 20}; // Resolves to B(std::initializer_list<int> )
   B b3{30};     // Resolves to B(std::initializer_list<int> )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between Object obj(args...) and Object obj{args...}? and why Scott says so.

The difference is that in the former case, the order of evaluation of arguments is  unsequenced (i.e unspecified) but in the latter case, the order is left-to-right (i.e in which they appear).

The following text from $5.2.2/8 [expr.call] (n3690) deals with `Object(args...)` form:

> The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the arguments are all **unsequenced** relative to one another. All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered (see 1.9).

And the text from $8.5.4/4 [dcl.init.list] (n3690) deals with `Object{args...}` form:

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are **evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is,
>   every value computation and side eﬀect associated with a given
>   initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side eﬀect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in
>   the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.[ Note: This
>   evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the
>   initialization; for example, it applies when the elements of the
>   initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call,
>   even though ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the
>   arguments of a call. — end note ]

Well which means this:

```
 int f() { static int i = 10; return ++i; }  //increment the static int!

 Object obj(f(), f()); //is it obj(11,12) or obj(12,11)? Unspecified. 

 Object obj{f(), f()}; //it is obj(11,12). Guaranteed.
```

Note that [GCC (4.7.0 and 4.7.2) have a bug because of which `{}` form doesn't work the way it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060264/order-of-evaluation-of-elements-in-list-initialization). I'm not sure if it is fixed in the current version.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between Object obj(args...) and Object obj{args...}?

{args...} will prefer a constructor with an initializer_list over other legal candidates.

```
std::vector<int> v(10); // vector of size 10
std::vector<int> v{10}; // vector initialized with a single element, (int) 10
```

On the other hand, you give up implicit narrowing.

```
std::vector<int> v(10.5); // vector of size 10
std::vector<int> v{10.5}; // illegal - no compile
std::vector<float> v{10.5}; // vector initialized with a single element, (float) 10.5
```