# Difference between the different ways to initialize std::string

Tags: c++, string, initialization

Lately I have been seeing quite a few people who initialize their `std::string`s like this:

```
std::string a{ "test" }; // Yes they do it with a single value
```

Now I wouldn't use this unless it's an array or to pass an initialization list.

But it got me curious, is there any point of doing this preferably over:

```
std::string a = "test";
std::string a ( "test" );
```

All three work without a doubt and I get the difference between the latter two.

Does it give some kind of performance improvement?

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877a30c2df55964c)

Comment: Look up C++11 uniform initialization. [Mildly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it give some kind of performance improvement?

No.

In the end, one `std::string` constructor gets called.  The only difference is how the compiler goes about choosing the constructor.

Developers will probably choose a style according to usage with classes where it DOES matter, perhaps because there are initialization-list constructors, or because of narrowing conversions or `explicit` constructors.  And then use the same style for strings just for the sake of consistency.

For `std::string` all three paths through the compiler end up choosing the same constructor.