# Frustrated when creating a pair of integers in C++

Tags: c++, types

I want to create a pair in C++

```
int x=3;
int y =4;
std::pair<int,int> mypair = std::make_pair<int,int>(x,y);
```

But i get this error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(int&, int&)’
     std::pair<int,int> mypair = std::make_pair<int,int>(x,y);
```

On the other hand,  if I use

```
std::pair<int,int> mypair = std::make_pair<int,int>(3,4);
```

then it works. Any explanation on ths? And how to make the first case above work so one can create a pair (x,y) wihtout pain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/c11-make-pair-with-specified-template-parameters-doesnt-compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
std::pair<int,int> mypair = std::make_pair(x,y);
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642232/2352671)

Comment: Thanks. Why  std::make<T,T> does not work?

Comment: @zell check the link in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

To make your first case work you can do

```
std::pair<int, int> mypair{x, y};
```

Comment: Thanks. What is that strange syntax?

Comment: That would be [uniform initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax)

Comment: This is C++11 initialization. If you are pre C++11 you can do `std::pair<int,int> mypair = std::pair<int,int>(x,y)` (to avoid the statement to look like a function declaration)

Comment: @tobi303 MVP doesn't apply here because `x` and `y` aren't types.

Comment: @TartanLlama oh yes, I was just wondering why he used the fancy brackets and then I was too fast in writing (well, faster than thinking)

Comment: I'd like to say, make_pair was introduced so you could create pair without specifying redundantly template arguments (ie: having to type <int, int>).
If you too want to avoid typing redundant stuff, I'd recommend using the auto keyword for mypair's type and initialize it with a make_pair