# Different way of initializing a object in c++

Tags: c++, class, object

Let us say I have a class named "Car". Let us also say that when initializing the object, you give two variables of type int. In the past, when ever I would want to create this object, I would do:

```
Car myCar(10, 5);
```

but I recently saw a slitly different way to do this:

```
Car myCar{10, 5};
```

What is the difference of using () or using {}?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612075/how-to-use-c11-uniform-initialization-syntax

Comment: https://arne-mertz.de/2015/07/new-c-features-uniform-initialization-and-initializer_list/